# how to create a function using python

Tags: python

Create a functions using python in which convert the temperature from fahrenheit to centigrade. Call this function into main program to print the values.

```
temperature_in_f=int(input("Enter temperature fahrenheit :"))
def f_to_c(temperature_in_f):
    temperature_in_c<(temperature_in_f-32)*5/9
    return temperature_in_c
print(temperature_in_c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you simply need to change `<` for an `=`

```
temperature_in_f = int(input("Enter temperature fahrenheit :"))

def f_to_c(temperature_in_f):
    temperature_in_c = (temperature_in_f - 32)*5/9
    return temperature_in_c

print(f"Temperature in centigrade : {f_to_c(temperature_in_f)}")
```

Comment: SRY BUT IT IS NOT RUNNING PROPERLY

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you've used the `<` operator instead of `=` for an assignment.

Change to:

```
temperature_in_c = (temperature_in_f-32)*5/9
#                ^ use = for variable assignment
```

Also, you aren't actually calling your function, so you need to:

```
print(f_to_c(temperature_in_f))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy

```
inp = int(input()) # integer input
def fToC(F): # Fahrenheit to Celsius
    C = (F - 32) * (5 / 9) # you used > it should be =
    return C # you could remove the variable C and just return the equation with F
NewC = fToC(inp)
print(NewC)
```

or more easily
print(fToC(input()))

Comment: SRY BUT IT IS NOT RUNNING PROPERLY